# JavaScript dynamic card rendering in inner HTML

Tags: javascript, for-loop, fetch, async.js

Spend much time but can't solve it. My CSS is OK. But why it is printing line by line in innerHTML? I am using an async function to get the data.
**1st Function**

```
const deploySnipCard = (getSnip) => {
    for (x in getSnip) {
        const tech = getSnip[x].tech;
        const tags = getSnip[x].tags;
        const tagsUrl = getSnip[x].tagsUrl;
        const status = getSnip[x].status;
        const imgSrc = getSnip[x].imgSrc;
        const imgUrl = getSnip[x].imgUrl;
        const caption = getSnip[x].caption;
        appendCard(tech, tags, tagsUrl, status, imgSrc, imgUrl, caption);
    }
};
```

**2nd Function**

```
const appendCard = (tech, tags, tagsUrl, status, imgSrc, imgUrl, caption) => {
    const mainDiv = document.getElementById("root");
    mainDiv.innerHTML += `
    <div class="col-12 col-lg-4 col-md-6">
        <div class="snip-card mt-5 p-2">
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
                <div>
                    <span class="badge bg-primary mb-2">${tech}</span>
                    <a href="${tagsUrl}">
                    <span class="badge bg-danger mb-2 mx-1">${tags}</span></a>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <span class="badge bg-success mb-2">${status}</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <a href="${imgUrl}">
                <div class="bg-dark">
                    <img class="card-img img-fluid" alt="click here" loading="lazy"
                        src="${imgSrc}">
                </div>
            </a>
            <p class="snip-card-cap my-2">${caption}</p>
        </div>
    </div>`;
};
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Expected Output:**

[image]

Comment: Are you using a js  library for doing the layout or is it all css based? If there is a js component then you will probably need to call some method that tells it the content has changed and needs a re-layout

Comment: `.innerHTML +=` reads the former HTML then adds HTML to it... which is a bad idea anyways, from a processing standpoint. What do you expect?

Comment: @PatrickEvans the layout is CSS based

Comment: @StackSlave Thank you for your observation. I did not find any better idea to do. Do you have any better ways to solve?

Comment: Use `const someElement = document.createElement('div')`, append other elements created the same way to as `someElement`, then `mainDiv.appendChild(someElement)`.